# Second order linear homogeneous ODE with constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In homework I was asked to find all solutions to the following ODE:
$$x''+ax'+bx = 0$$
After reading, I know the following.

**(a)**
If $t^2+at+b = (t-\lambda_1)(t-\lambda_2)$ with $\lambda_1\ne\lambda_2$, then
$$x(t) = c_1e^{\lambda_1 t}+c_2e^{\lambda_2 t} $$ 
is the general solution.

**(b)**
If $t^2+at+b = (t-\lambda)^2$ then $x(t) = (c_1+c_2t)e^{\lambda t}$
is the general solution.

---

**EDIT**
I know why and when these are solutions, but this is not my question. My question is how to show if $x(t)$ satisfies this equation, then it **must be** in one of the two forms. Not that these two forms are solutions.

**EDIT**
Set $y = (x,x')$, then $y' = F(y) = (y(2),-a\cdot y(2)-b\cdot y(1))$
If I know $F(y)$ is locally Lipschitz then by Picard–Lindelöf theorem solution is unique.

Comment: actually  @mezhang  as  i know,solution of  such kind of differental  equation is intuitely,i was told  like this by my professors,that  why you  may  think  why exponential  solution is because of this.let wait  from others what they  will say

Comment: @dato I'm thoroughly convinced with the intuition and they are solutions. But I'm not convinced that no other solutions can exist. I am told they are the only solutions, but that does not solve my problem. **I want a proof that no other solutions can exist**. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: because  such kind of equation is depend on characteristic equation,then it could  not be happen that  this has equation has more then  3 case,but if we imagine except    discriminant method,there is another one,then it will be  discovering new method for such equation

Comment: With suitable substitution, you should be able to convert the $2^{nd}$ order ODE to first. Picard lindeloff theorem guarantees the uniqueness, conditionally.

Comment: @user1709828 yes this is the answer that I was waiting for. Thank you.

Comment: @user1709828 please check if what I wrote is good in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could quote a more general uniqueness theorem, and even prove it. But we will stick to the particular type of equation. And, in order to use only first-year calculus material, we will **assume** that $r^2+ra+b=0$ does not have non-real solutions.

Given any initial conditions $x(0)=p$, $x'(0)=q$, there is a solution of the type you mention.

Call that solution $x_0$. We want to show that that there is no other solution. Suppose that $x_1$ is a solution of the same initial value problem. Let $y=x_1-x_0$. Then $y''+ay'+by=0$ and $y(0)=y'(0)=0$.

We want to show that this forces $y=0$. Consider the function $z=ye^{kt}$. Substituting, after some calculation we get 
$$z'' +(2k+a)z' + (k^2+ak+b)z=0.$$
Choose $k$ so that $k^2+ak+b=0$. 
Then we have arrived at an equation of the form 
$$z'' -cz'=0.$$
Put $w=z'$.  We are looking at the equation $w'=cw$, with the initial condition $w(0)=0$.

Any solution of $w'=cw$ has shape $Ae^{ct}$. The usual way to prove this is to consider the function $f(t)=\frac{w}{e^{ct}}$. Differentiate. We get that $f'(t)$ is identically $0$. So by the Mean Value Theorem, $f(t)$ is a constant. Thus $w=Ae^{ct}$ for some $A$. But since $w(0)=0$, we have $A=0$.

So $w$ is identically $0$. Thus $z'$ is identically $0$. It follows that $z$ is a constant. Since $z(0)=0$, this constant is $0$.

Comment: Please check if what I wrote below is good.

Comment: umm, if we don't have initial values, but asking about general form of solutions, how do I transform my argument such that I show "uniqueness" of the general form?

Comment: @mezhang: The argument looks correct. Whether it is viewed as good for a homework solution depends on what background theorems you have by this time. As in my solution, we can always specify generic initial values.

Comment: this is for analysis and we have proved Picard–Lindelöf theorem using Banach fixed point theorem. So I think it is adequate.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [user1709828](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345974/second-order-linear-homogeneous-ode-with-constant-coefficients#comment744448_345974). Transform into first order ODE.
$$y' = F(y) = (y(2), -a\cdot y(2)-b\cdot y(1))$$
Claim $F$ is Lipschitz.

**Proof**:
$|F(x)-F(y)| = \sqrt{|x_2-y_2|^2+(a(x_2-y_2)+b(x_1-y_1))^2} = \sqrt{(a^2+1)|x_2-y_2|^2+b^2|x_1-y_1|^2+2ab\cdot |x_2-y_2|\cdot|x_1-y_1|} \\
\le \sqrt{\max(a^2+1,b^2)\cdot (|x_1-y_1|^2+|x_2-y_2|^2)+|ab|\cdot (|x_1-y_1|^2+|x_2-y_2|^2)}\\
< L \sqrt{|x_1-y_1|^2+|x_2+y_2|^2} = L |x-y|$

where $L> \sqrt{\max(a^2+1,b^2)+|ab|}$

By Picard-Lindel$\ddot{o}$f theorem $F(y)$ is Lipschitz, given any initial condition $y(t_0) = (x_0,x'_0)$ solution exists and is unique.
For case (1) $\forall (x_0,x'_0)\in \mathbb{C}^2.\;Ae^{\lambda_1 t_0}+ Be^{\lambda_2 t_0} = x_0, \lambda_1Ae^{\lambda_1 t_0}+ \lambda_2Be^{\lambda_2 t_0} = x'_0$ has unique pair $(Ae^{\lambda_1 t_0},Be^{\lambda_2 t_0})$ that satisfy the equation since $(1,1)$ and $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ are linearly independent vectors. Therefore unique pair $(A,B)$ that both satisfy the initial condition and the ODE by above theorem.

Therefore for any given initial condition $(x_0,x'_0)$ solutions are in the form $x(t) = Ae^{\lambda_1 t}+Be^{\lambda_2 t}$. Similar for case (2).

Answer (score 0):

you need  to consider
1.when   determinant  of  characteristic equation (D)  is positive  ,in this case  you have two  real distinct root and colution is
  $c_1*e^{k_1*x}+c_2*e^{k_2*x}$

where     $k_1,k_2$  are roots of quadratic characteristic equation.

2.when  $D=0$

$y(t)=(c_1+t*c_2)*e^{k*x}$

again  $k$  root of  characteristic equation(actual you have  two solution  with $k_1=k_2$)

(algebraic multiplicity)

$D<0$

complex solution  $k_1=p+q*i$

$k_2=p-q*i$

$y(t)=e^{-p*t}*(c_1*cos q*t+c_2*sin q*t)$

Comment: you tell me what I know. I want to prove that all solutions are in these form, not that these forms are solutions.

Comment: see my comment   above please